Serving Terrain RGB tiles from XYZ / GeoTIFF files
I am trying to find a way to serve Terrain RGB tiles like these:
https://blog.mapbox.com/global-elevation-data-6689f1d0ba65
from a local server for a very large area. My source files are GeoTIFF files with 1x1km size or XYZ files with 1x1 km size.
Ultimately, it would be nice to have a db wich automatically serves the correct Z/X/Y file.
Is there a way to to that?

There is a tutorial about converting GeoTIFF DEM into rgb tiles in https://github.com/syncpoint/terrain-rgb/blob/master/README.md

A detailed tutorial about how to convert geo-tiff files containing
Digital Elevation Model (DEM) data into a pyramid of png files. The
tiles go into an MBTiles container in order to host them offline with
MBTileserver.

